# Where is objc_msgSend once you upgrade to Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode5

This code was working yesterday:

```
id urlNSString = objc_msgSend(objc_getClass("NSString"), sel_registerName("stringWithUTF8String:"), "http://zmangames.com/product-details.php?id=1246");
objc_msgSend(objc_getClass("EAGLView"), sel_registerName("openURL:"), urlNSString);
```

I just upgraded to Xcode 5, and now it says that function is not defined. I'm doing

```
#include <objc/message.h>
#include <objc/objc.h>
#include <objc/runtime.h>
```

Which seems to be in /usr/include/objc, and seems to include definitions of the function. I don't get any other complaints from the whole project.

Codesense says the definition looks like this:

```
OBJC_EXPORT id objc_msgSend(id self, SEL op, ...) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_0, __IPHONE_2_0);
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this instead of just writing normal Objective-C code?

Comment: I'm in a .cpp file, and the Obj-C compiler is not activated.

Comment: Hes probably writing c or c++

Comment: Seems like you could write Objective-C++ code or something...eh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. Did not check the error closely enough.

`Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Class' (aka 'objc_class *') to 'id' (aka 'objc_object *') for 1st argument`

Just have to cast the return value from objc_getClass from `Class` to `id`, like so:

```
id urlNSString = objc_msgSend((id)objc_getClass("NSString"), sel_registerName("stringWithUTF8String:"), "http://zmangames.com/product-details.php?id=1246");
objc_msgSend((id)objc_getClass("EAGLView"), sel_registerName("openURL:"), urlNSString);
```

Comment: Why don't you just make that file a `.mm` file instead of using all that baggage?

Comment: It is someone else's codebase, and it is mission-critical code. It's releasing on the App Store Oct 3, and I'm not doing something I am unsure of until I can get some testing behind it. Otherwise, you make a good point. :)

Comment: OK - being mission critical sounds like an even better reason to dump that nonsense.

Comment: Got some time to change this, it's now a .mm file with a proper Obj-C call. But this still answered the actual question. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `#import <objc/runtime.h>` instead.